# Raspberry Pi - Raspbian Lite - Waveshare 2.8 Inch Display - Openbox/nodm - Tkinter dispaly error

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, display, openbox

I followed the steps by tjohnson in his post here:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57128/how-to-boot-into-own-python-script-gui-only

and was able to get a Python3 Tkinter app running at startup on a raspberry pi using Raspbian Lite. This was using an external HDMI display.

I then installed a Waveshare 2.8 inch display and installed the drivers referenced on their site. The display itself works fine for interacting with the console.

Now, when the pi boots, the Tkinter app does not load as it did with an HDMI-connected display. I just see the console login prompt.

If, on the pi (directly at the device, not over SSH) I run:

```
python3 /home/pi/App/my_script.py
```

I get the the following:

tkinter.TclError: no display name and no DISPLAY environment variable

Clearly there is something about the configuration of the Waveshare display that is making it so that I can't run a tkinter app on it. I did a good amount of troubleshooting there but could not find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pick on from [`[tkinter] "no display"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+%22no+display%22)

Comment: Thanks, stovfl. Looked through a bunch of these. Most of these seem to involve running a script over SSH or otherwise remotely. Didn't find anything that seems to work.

Comment: Relevant [what-is-display-0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193827/what-is-display-0) and [How do I set the DISPLAY variable on Linux](https://support.objectplanet.com/esupport/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=17)

Comment: Thanks. It seems installation of the Waveshare drivers is breaking the display. After installing the Waveshare drivers, I can run cd LCD-show/ &
./LCD-hdmi to switch to HDMI display and after reboot, the tkinter app does not load anymore on the HDMI display. From console, running echo $DISPLAY returns nothing.

Comment: ***"`echo $DISPLAY` returns nothing"***: Create one by your own. Which `X-Server` are you running?

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly novice with Linux, so I'll try my best... pidof X && echo "yes" doesn't return anything so I don't think an x-server is running. Which I think may make sense because openbox did not start at boot. To be sure, I'm running Raspbian Lite which as I understand it does not itself have an x-server and this is what openbox would do at boot.

Comment: Also, if when using HDMI display I run "exec openbox" I get: Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY environment variable.

Comment: To be clear, are we talking about [Openbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202124/discussion-between-stovfl-and-dglurn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to stovfl (who went above and beyond in helping me troubleshoot)... I got the display and the tkinter app working with Openbox/nodm/Raspbian Lite.

Used this article as a resource:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1050620

Because it did not exist, I created the dir and file:
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf

Contents of the file:

```
Section "InputClass" 
Identifier "calibration" 
MatchProduct "ADS7846 Touchscreen" 
Option "Calibration" "160 3723 3896 181" 
Option "SwapAxes" "1" 
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
# WaveShare SpotPear 3.5", framebuffer 1 
Identifier "uga" 
driver "fbdev" 
#Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1" 
Option "ShadowFB" "off" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
# Primary monitor. WaveShare SpotPear 480x320 
Identifier "WSSP" 
EndSection

Section "Screen" 
Identifier "primary" 
Device "uga" 
Monitor "WSSP" 
EndSection 

Section "ServerLayout" 
Identifier "default" 
Screen 0 "primary" 0 0
EndSection
```

Note that commenting out this line:

```
Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
```

was key to making things work.

Comment: Also, really only the Device and Screen sections are necessary. The rest if commented out will still allow the display to work.